# Cleveref sorting doesn't work correctly if theorem shares subsection counter

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, cleveref, thmtools

In the MWE below, the theorems should be sorted as "1.2 and 2.1" rather than "2.1 and 1.2". The correct sorting behavior is obtained by replacing `sibling=subsection` with `parent=section` but of course then the theorem counter is not shared with subsection.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\declaretheorem[sibling=subsection]{theorem}
%\declaretheorem[parent=section]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{}
\begin{theorem}
Blah.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\label{theorem}
Blah.
\end{theorem}

\section{}
\begin{theorem}\label{othertheorem}
Blah.
\end{theorem}

\Cref{theorem,othertheorem}.

\end{document}
```

I suppose the issue arises from a difference in how a `subsection` label is written to the aux file vs a new theorem counter, but how do I make this work correctly?

Comment: There are not subsections in your MWE.

Comment: It seems I misunderstood your question. You already have a solution, but for some reason you want to use `sibling=subsection` ? Could you please clarify?

Comment: Please see my  updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note**. The bug below will likely be fixed in the next release. https://github.com/muzimuzhi/thmtools/commit/0f9a1cf0ecdf26b4d1a5c6fd8fe27c912e919d5a

Actually, digging through the `cleveref` code a bit more, I am now convinced that this is a bug in `thmtools`.

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}[subsection]{Theorem}


\begin{document}

\section{}
\begin{theorem}
Blah.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\label{theorem}
Blah.
\end{theorem}

\section{}
\begin{theorem}\label{othertheorem}
Blah.
\end{theorem}

\Cref{theorem,othertheorem}.

\end{document}
```

With `thmtools` not loaded, the aux file shows the correct output.

```
\newlabel{theorem}{{1.2}{1}}
\newlabel{theorem@cref}{{[theorem][2][1]1.2}{[1][1][]1}}
...
\newlabel{othertheorem}{{2.1}{1}}
\newlabel{othertheorem@cref}{{[theorem][1][2]2.1}{[1][1][]1}}
```

But if you uncomment the loading of `thmtools`, you get

```
\newlabel{theorem}{{1.2}{1}}
\newlabel{theorem@cref}{{[theorem][2][]1.2}{[1][1][]1}}
...
\newlabel{othertheorem}{{2.1}{1}}
\newlabel{othertheorem@cref}{{[theorem][1][]2.1}{[1][1][]1}}
```

As indicated by the fact that [Simon Dispa's patch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/598213/119) works, this seems that the inclusion of `thmtools` actually forcibly bypassed the code placed into `cleveref` that were designed to handle precisely the situation of sibling counters and checking for parents.

Suggestions:

- Switch to using either `amsthm` or `ntheorem`, and drop `thmtools`.
- Alternatively, send the maintainers of `thmtools` a note (maybe pointing to this answer). Something in their package is screwing things up, but I don't have the time to track it down now.

---

#### Updated Workaround

Below is a simpler workaround for your issue.

Use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\declaretheorem[sibling=subsection]{theorem}

\counterwithin{theorem}{section} %%% <---- NEW LINE

\begin{document}
...
```

Brief explanation: with the LaTeX native `\newtheorem` defined in `latex.ltx`, as well as the implementations in `ntheorem` and in `amsthm`, the above would *not* work. The reason is that their when you declare a sibling counter, the underlying counter used for the environment **is** the sibling counter. So `\newtheorem{theorem}[subsection]{Theorem}` never creates a new theorem, it just internally marks that `theorem` should use `subsection` as the underlying counter.

The implementation in `thmtools` is different. To support `autoref` when you declare a sibling counter, what it does is create an alias for the sibling counter.

The neat thing that happens with this definition is that, for all intents and purposes it appears that there is a counter called `theorem`. It is just that underneath it the counter register is the same as that used for `subsection`. So that when you call `\stepcounter{theorem}`, you will see that the `subsection` counter also goes up by one. And you can also do things like `\arabic{theorem}` to show the arabic numeral representation of the `subsection` counter.

What `thmtools` doesn't do, however, is re-register the counter into the reset list of its sibling. Functionally for the purpose of resetting the counter, this is inconsequential. Registering both `theorem` and `subsection` into the reset list for `section` would just mean that when `section` is stepped, first `subsection` will reset to zero, then `theorem` (which is really `subsection`) will again reset to zero. So there's not much point of registering both.

However, from the point of view of `cleveref`, which reads the reset list to determine which counters are reset by which others, this makes a difference. Even though `theorem` is secretly `subsection` and hence is reset by `section`, it is not "obviously so" when looking at the reset list!

If would be nice if `thmtools` can be updated to help out `cleveref` and other packages that read the reset list by doing this registration. But since that is not the case, you can do it yourself. As mentioned before, `theorem` behaves pretty much like a normal counter. So you can just go ahead and call `\counterwithin`. In terms of actually resetting the counter, it makes no impact. But now `cleveref` can see the parent-child relation.

Comment: The issue is now tracked in https://github.com/muzimuzhi/thmtools/issues/22.

Comment: @ronno: I did a bit more diving to help the maintainer track down the issue. Which also helped me come up with probably the simplest workaround in this situation. See the update.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**

This patch will solve the issue *as presented in the MWE* using `\declaretheorem[sibling=subsection]{theorem}` by adding an ordering reference number.

Previously, Theorem 1.2 was referenced to as `Theorem #2 of nothing` and Theorem 2.1 as `Theorem #1 of nothing`. Naturally, they were arranged in the wrong order, with second in the first place.

Adding the ordering reference number, now the reference  to Theorem 1.2 is `Theorem #2 of 1` and to Theorem 2.1  `Theorem #1 of 2`, so the sort order is correct.

[image: z]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\declaretheorem[sibling=subsection]{theorem}

%%%************************************************* added
\makeatletter
\def\refstepcounter@noarg#1{% 
    \cref@old@refstepcounter{#1}%
    \cref@constructprefix{#1}{\cref@result}%
    \@ifundefined{cref@#1@alias}%
    {\def\@tempa{#1}}%
    {\def\@tempa{\csname cref@#1@alias\endcsname}}%
    \ifx\cref@result\@empty%
    \def\cref@result{\thesection}%
    \fi%
    \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{%
        [\@tempa][\arabic{#1}][\cref@result]%
        \csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}}%
\makeatother
%%%*************************************************


\begin{document}
    
    \section{}
    \begin{theorem}
        Blah.
    \end{theorem}
    
    \begin{theorem}\label{theorem}
        Blah.
    \end{theorem}
    
    \section{}
    \begin{theorem}\label{othertheorem}
        Blah.
    \end{theorem}
    
    \Cref{theorem,othertheorem}.
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't see why that should matter. I think you switched the theorem definition to use `parent=section` which (as I mention in the question) works fine. If you take the code in your answer and switch the theorem declaration then in the output you get "Theorems 2.1, 1.2 and 2.4".

Comment: @ronno   I updated the answer  using `\declaretheorem[sibling=subsection]{theorem}`

Comment: Thanks for the update, can you explain what your `\def` is doing? Is it making every label/ref be compared first by the section number?

Comment: The code patches the same code from `cleveref`. The original code calls `...constructprefix...` to store the parent counter value into `\cref@result`, and writes it to the aux file. The updated code adds a check: whenever `\cref@result` returns empty (meaning `cleveref` cannot find a parent counter), the added code sets it to default to `section`.

Comment: Actually, it is surprising to me that @Simon's patch works: it seems to indicate that `thmtools` doesn't work as advertised. With `amsthm` or `ntheorem` and the sibling counter, `cleveref` should **never** visit the `noarg` branch of `\refstepcounter`. It should use the version with the optional argument, as `cleveref` patches the theorem creation code in `amsthm` and `ntheorem` so that they call `\refstepcounter[theorem]{subsection}` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: make `subsection` track `theorem`, instead of the other way around.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\let\originalsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand\subsection[1]{%
        \setcounter{subsection}{\value{theorem}}%
        \stepcounter{theorem}%
        \originalsubsection{#1}}

\declaretheorem[parent=section]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{}
\begin{theorem}
Blah.
\end{theorem}

\subsection{Blank}

\begin{theorem}\label{theorem}
Blah.
\end{theorem}


\section{Test}
\begin{theorem}\label{othertheorem}
Blah.
\end{theorem}

\Cref{theorem,othertheorem}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Brief diagnosis:*

`thmtools`+`cleveref` writes stuff like

```
\newlabel{othertheorem@cref}{{[theorem][1][2]2.1}{[1][1][]1}}
```

into the aux field. Inside the second set of braces are instructions on how `cleveref` is supposed to interpet the label. First bracket is the counter type (usually counter name, but with `thmtools` / `amsthm` / `ntheorem` it tracks the name of the environment instead, since they frequently share the same counter), the second bracket is the counter value, and the third is the parent counter value. If you use `thmtools` to declare a `sibling` counter, and the counter is not one of the theorem counters, somehow the parent/numberwithin information is lost.

There may be a way to fix this by patching `cleveref` and/or `amsthm`/`thmtools`. But the above workaround is cheaper.

Comment: Guess following your diagnosis: maybe `thmtools`+`cleveref` cannot tell if a general counter provided as sibling is `numberwithin`ed some other counter and take care of that?

Comment: It is a bit more complicated than that. TeX internals does not have a good way to look up what are the counters that resets a given counter. Internally what is kept, for each counter, is a list of the counters that the given counter resets. To look up the reverse information you have to search through all counters, and check whether your counter is reset by it. (Also I think the resetting-by may be non-unique.) `Cleveref` only checks whether your counter is reset by the standard sectioning commands.

Comment: See my second answer for some additional thoughts.