# Hyperlink prints OK but jumps to wrong target

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref, hyperlink, crossreftools

When I use pdflatex to process a book-length document, in chapter 6 a couple of isolated links to theorem-like environments in that same chapter appear printed correctly in the pdf output, but clicking those links takes one to the same-numbered item in a different chapter!

Specifically, the link whose text is "Example 6.9" jumps to Example 1.9, and the link whose text is "Proposition 6.12" jumps to "Proposition 6.12".

The labels of the wrongly jumped-to targets are definitely entirely different from the labels of the intended targets.

What could be wrong?

Alas, so far I cannot produce a MWE. The preamble is split over a dozen separate files.

To help in the diagnosis, below are:

- extracts from the source where the relevant labels are defined and where they are cross-referenced;
- corresponding entries in the .aux files; and
- extracted sections of the preamble files where theorem-like environments are defined and cross-referencing (hyperref, cleveref, crossreftools, etc.) is set up.

Wrong jump #1 - source in chapter 6 correctly prints in pdf as "Example 6.9":

Show that the quotient space $\mathbb{R} /!/ \mathbb{Q}$ of \cref{ex:non-cr-quot-cr} is in fact not a Hausdorff space.

*Wrong jump #1* — target, again in chapter 6, is the following (but link jumps to 1.9 instead):

```
Show that the quotient space $\mathbb{R} /\!/ \mathbb{Q}$ 
of \cref{ex:non-cr-quot-cr} is in fact not a Hausdorff space.
```

*Wrong jump #1* — target, again in chapter 6, is the following (but link jumps to 1.9 instead):

```
\begin{example}
\label{ex:non-cr-quot-cr}
\index{line with two origins!separation properties@and separation properties}%
\index{line with two origins!quotient space@as quotient space}

The line with two origins ....
\end{example}
```

*Wrong jump #1* — .aux extract:

```
\@@wrindexm@m{topology2}{Cartesian sum!completely regular space@and completely regular space|hyperpage}{589}
\@writefile{loe}{\contentsline {example}{\ifthmt@listswap \MakeUppercase  {e}xample~6.9\else \numberline {6.9}\MakeUppercase  {e}xample\fi }{590}{example.9}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{ex:non-cr-quot-cr}{{\M@TitleReference {6.9}{Completely regular spaces}}{590}{}{example.9}{}}
\newlabel{ex:non-cr-quot-cr@cref}{{[example][9][]6.9}{[1][590][]590}}
\@writefile{lla}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {\crtrefnumber{ex:non-cr-quot-cr}}ex:non-cr-quot-cr}{590}{example.9}\protected@file@percent }
```

*Wrong jump #2* — source in chapter 6 is correctly printed in pdf as "Proposition 6.12":

```
Prove \cref{prop:closed-subspace-of-normal}: a closed subspace 
of a normal space is itself normal.
```

*Wrong jump #2* — target, again in chapter 6, is the following (but link jumps instead to 2.12):

```
\begin{proposition}
\label{prop:closed-subspace-of-normal}    
A closed subspace of a normal space is itself normal.    
\end{proposition}
```

*Wrong jump #2* — .aux extract:

```
\@@wrindexm@m{topology2}{subspace!normal space@of normal space|(hyperpage}{591}
\@writefile{loe}{\contentsline {proposition}{\numberline {6.12}Proposition}{591}{proposition.12}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{prop:closed-subspace-of-normal}{{\M@TitleReference {6.12}{Normal spaces}}{591}{}{proposition.12}{}}
\newlabel{prop:closed-subspace-of-normal@cref}{{[proposition][12][]6.12}{[1][591][]591}}
\@writefile{lla}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {\crtrefnumber{prop:closed-subspace-of-normal}}prop:closed-subspace-of-normal}{591}{proposition.12}\protected@file@percent }
```

*From the preamble:*

```
%% MATH & THEOREMS
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\RequirePackage{thmtools}

\swapnumbers % Invert numbers/labels

\newcommand{\thmlikefont}{\sffamily\bfseries}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\thmlikefont,
  headpunct={\thmlikefont.},
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\thmlikefont,
  headformat=\NAME\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\mdseries,
  spaceabove=12pt,spacebelow=12pt,
  hidealllines=true,
  innerleftmargin=8pt,innerrightmargin=8pt,
  postheadhook={%
    \ifx\@empty\thmt@shortoptarg
      \renewcommand\addcontentsline[3]{}
    \fi}
]{thmstyle}
\theoremstyle{thmstyle}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont= \thmlikefont,
  headpunct={\thmlikefont.},
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\thmlikefont,
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  spaceabove=12pt,spacebelow=12pt
]{defstyle}
\declaretheorem[
  style=defstyle,
  numberlike=theorem,
  preheadhook=\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\myDiamond$}\pushQED{\qed},
  postfoothook=\popQED
  ]
{example}

%%  CROSS-REFERENCING
\RequirePackage{xurl}

\usepackage{datetime2} % to satisfy the "\today" in \hypersetup
\DTMusemodule{english}{en-US}

\RequirePackage{hyperxmp} % to add metadata info into pdf
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  unicode,
  pdfapart=2, pdfaconformance=u,
  bookmarksnumbered,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=3,
  breaklinks=true,
  colorlinks, citecolor=red, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue,
  linktocpage=true,linktoc=all,
  pdftitle={Topology, Second Edition},
  % ...(other entries re author, publication, etc.)...
   pdfproducer=pdfTeX-1.40.23, %why needed ????????????
}

% Allow link to page with label -- patch by Martin Scharrer
% cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19416/9237
\let\orig@Hy@EveryPageAnchor\Hy@EveryPageAnchor
\def\Hy@EveryPageAnchor{%
    \begingroup
    \hypersetup{pdfview=Fit}%
    \orig@Hy@EveryPageAnchor
    \endgroup
}
% My commands to use that
% Usage: \crefpagetext{text-to-appar-in-link}{lbl} with usual \label{lbl} for target.
\newcommand{\crefpagetext}[2]{\hyperlink{page.\getpagerefnumber{#2}}{#1} on \cpageref{#2}}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\crefpagetext*[2]{\hyperlink{page.\getpagerefnumber{#2}}{#1}}

\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypersetup{hidelinks}}}

%% Allow ref to section n, not section m.n
% From "trickier version" by Christian Hupfer
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383608/13492
\let\@xp\expandafter
%
% Stripping the dot from the 1.2 -like reference
\def\@@stripdot#1.#2\@nil{#2}
%
% Stripping the memoir stuff from the reference, i.e. \M@TitleReference {1.2}{FOO} and handing #1 (1.2) over to the \@@stripdot macro
\def\@stripdot\M@TitleReference #1#2\@nil{\@@stripdot#1\@nil}
%
%Macro, second level of expansion
\newcommand{\stripdot}[1]{%
  \@xp\@stripdot#1\@nil
}
\newcommand{\crefsec}[1]{%
  % Expand the argument first
  \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#1}{%
    % Do nothing if #1 is not defined
  }{%
    \hyperlink{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{anchor}{}}{\@xp\stripdot\@xp{\getrefnumber{#1}}}%
  }%
}

\RequirePackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
\RequirePackage{crossreftools}
% Fix to crossreftools
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512175/13492
\renewcommand{\@@crtextr@ct@ref}[2]{%
  \expandafter\@@@crtextr@ct@ref\expandafter{\detokenize{#2}}{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\@@@crtextr@ct@ref}[2]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname r@#1\endcsname\relax
  \crt@refundefined%
  \else
  \expandafter\expandafter\csname crt@ref@splitter@#2\endcsname\csname r@#1\endcsname%
  \fi
}

\crefname{proposition}{Proposition}{Propositions}
\Crefname{proposition}{Proposition}{Propositions}
\crefname{example}{Example}{Examples}
\Crefname{example}{Example}{Examples}

% Added 2020-03-17
% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/reference-name-of-description-list-item-in-latex
\def\namedlabel#1#2{\begingroup
    #2%
    \def\@currentlabel{#2}%
    \phantomsection\label{#1}\endgroup
}
```

Many other packages are loaded, including `babel`, but I *think* the ones shown in the preceding preamble extract are the relevant ones.

**Added 2022-04-28 attempted fixes**

I tried suggestions from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/642073/13492, but without success:

1. Replacing the `\newtheorem` declarations to corresponding ones from `thmtools`. Thus I used the following, which does *not* eliminate the wrong jumps:

   ```
   \declaretheorem[name=Theorem, style=thmstyle, numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}

   \declaretheorem[name=Proposition, style=thmstyle, numberlike=theorem]{proposition}
   \declaretheorem[name=Definition, style=defstyle, numberlike=theorem]{definition}
   ```
2. I was unable to match the git diff file for `aliascntr.dtx` with the existing version of that `aliascntr.dtx` in TeXLive 2022.
3. In addition to the changes indicated in #1, I added the `\counterwithin` statements from 3:

   ```
    \counterwithin{proposition}{chapter}
    \counterwithin{example}{chapter}
   ```

*Now the jumps *seem* to be correct!*

Given the size and complexity of the book and its source files, I need to continue sampling link jumps to verify that all is now well.

Comment: sorry but you really should know that such snippets are useless. check the log-file for warning about duplicated destinations and resolve them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: How can such a duplicate destination elsewhere affect instances as I report? The labels in question are not duplicated elsewhere in the source.

Comment: Does it help if you replace `\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}` with the analogous statement using the `thmtools` syntax of `\declaretheorem....`? It makes me nervous that you are mixing the two. (My impression the last time I dug into `thmtools` code is that they are not exactly equivalents.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `aux` file output, I have a suspicion that you are running into the same (or at least very similar) bug that [I diagnosed in this previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/598450/119).

While a patch has been checked into the Git repo, a release has **not** been made onto CTAN (the current version is dated August 2020). If I were you I would try a few different things:

1. First try to see [changing everything to `thmtools` syntax helps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642041/hyperlink-prints-ok-but-jumps-to-wrong-target#comment1600365_642041). I am pessimistic that this will solve your problem.
2. If you feel confident at mucking about with package internals: make a copy of the `aliasctr.sty` file from `thmtools` into your working directory, and apply [the changes indicated in the Git commit fixing this bug](https://github.com/muzimuzhi/thmtools/commit/0f9a1cf0ecdf26b4d1a5c6fd8fe27c912e919d5a).
3. Alternatively, if you are not confident mucking about, I would suggest trying the following workaround:

   - Step 1: change the declaration of `proposition` to `thmtools` syntax. (This is important, this workaround depends on how `\declaretheorem` works and will fail with `\newtheorem`.)
   - Step 2: add, after declaring `proposition` and `example`, the following two lines (for an explanation of why this may work, see the first link to my diagnoses above)

   ```
   \counterwithin{proposition}{chapter}
   \counterwithin{example}{chapter}
   ```
4. Alternatively: you can also rewrite everything using completely just `amsthm` syntax and not `thmtools`. The syntax for `amsthm` is certainly clunkier, but the code does work with `cleveref`. (I've generally avoided using `thmtools` myself now.)

Comment: I have doubts that some incompability between cleveref and thmtools affects the destination names. The name is stored with a normal label command and not in the cleveref label.  The snippets in the question show the names `proposition.12` and `example.9` and that is simply not unique as it doesn't contain the chapter number.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It is not a incompatibility between cleveref and thmtools per se: the way `thmtools` handled multiple environments sharing the same counter was buggy. `amsthm` for example just pointed the counter to the one it is supposed to duplicate. But `thmtools` internally created a duplicate alias counter, and **very crucially, forgets to add the duplicate counter to the reset-by list**. So if `hyperref` is picking up on the `proposition` counter, it would not know that it would be reset by `chapter`. Hence the hypertarget is duplicated (missing chapter number).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer at least, the above is my guess of what is happening, since the duplicated destination is most likely due to a counter being reset outside of the knowledge of hyperref. This is similar to what happened in the cleveref case. I would test it if the OP had provided a MWE that I can play with.

Comment: I quite believe that there is perhaps a bug. But that doesn't really matter. hyperref tries to make the names unique, but its method is not fool proof (and isn't meant to be). The correct way to resolve something faulty destination names from the point of view of hyperref is to manually define \theH<counter> so that it works and not rely on hyperref's guesses.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer please do write an answer explaining that.

Comment: no sorry, but the question is not in a state that I want to write an answer. Without complete example there is too much guessing involved.

Comment: As suspected, solution #1, replacing all `\newtheorem` definitions with the corresponding `\declaretheorem` from `thmtools`, does not fix the wrong-jump issue.

Comment: @WillieWong: I do not see how to edit aliasctr.dtx so as to incorporate the git commit: the diff file from github lists as present lines that I do not see in the version of aliasctr.dtx that I have with TeXLIve 2022. E.g., there are lines missing from my aliasctr.dtx that are shown in the git commit as present, either to remain or to be replaced or deleted! How to do this?

Comment: @WillieWong: do commands such as `\counterwithin{proposition}{chapter}` do something different from what the option `numberlike=theorem` to `\declaretheorem` does?

Comment: @murray the short answer is that the `numberlike=theorem` or `sibling=theorem` options from `\declaretheorem` is_intended_ to not require this additional call to `\counterwithin`, but there's a bug which made it necessary. For the long answer, see my conversation with Ulrike above, and also the previous answer of mine. // Regarding the `aliasctr` lines: you may have to look through the GitHub commits if you want to incorporate all the changes since the last released version. If the workaround is ok, I'd suggest waiting for the official release.